# Pyomo DataPortal Not Working with Multiple Indices (Abstract Model, CSV Import)

Tags: python, csv, pyomo

I am trying to import CSV data using the DataPortal setup in Pyomo for an abstract model.

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = AbstractModel()
model.t = Set()  # year index
model.a = Set()  # type of resource index
model.q = Set()  # zone index
model.EERF = Param(model.a, model.q, model.t)  # feedstock production

data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename='EERBiomassProd.csv', param=model.EERF, index=(model.t, model.q, model.a))
instance = model.create_instance(data)
```

The CSV I am importing from has four columns with many rows.

| year | zone | source | tons |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | california | herbaceous | 2 |
| 2020 | california | waste | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2050 | utah/nevada | woody | 900 |

There are a total of 4 year values, 10 zones, and 3 sources. I want these to each be indices of my parameter, with the value of the parameter set to the "tons" column.

I am getting the following error from Python when I run my code.

```
RuntimeError: Failed to set value for param=EERF, index=(2020, 'california', 'herbaceous'), value=2.
    source error message=unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'type'
```

Advice? Can I try importing the data in another way, like with a Pandas data frame? Should I manually write out what each of the indices are instead of trying to read them from the CSV using DataPortal (e.g., `model.t = Set(initialize=[2020, 2030, 2040, 2050])`)?

Comment: Is `EERBiomassProd.csv` available somewhere?

Comment: I've set my working directory to be where the csv is stored, if that's what you're asking, so Python has no issues accessing the CSV. I show the CSV structure above.

Comment: Yes the problem is not there. I was asking if you mind sharing your file. Thus, someone can try to replicate your problem

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow. Are there recommended ways to share files? It doesn't seem like I can upload files.

Comment: Nevermind. There's no need to share your file. Just tried and even with the 3 rows you mentioned, the problem occurs. (PS: welcome to stackoverflow!)

Comment: Have you already checked this out? https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_abstractmodels/data/dataportals.html I'm sorry, I don't know pyomo and I do not have a quick hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for trouble...  :)

The problem you are running into by reading the data like that is the inference back from the multi-dimensional set to individual sets.  I don't think `pyomo` can do that naturally.  You can probably torture out the individual sets from the 3-dim index, but probably not worth it.  You are going to have issues w/ duplicates, etc. that `pyomo` would have to sort out.  It is likely there are many duplicates within the indices (2020 will occur many times, and same for California, etc).

The first example below reads your data (using a similar .csv posted below), but only gets as far as capturing the 3-dim index.  Perhaps that is "good enough" but unlikely.

If you want to stay in "abstract land" you should probably disagregate your sets into separate data fields/files etc., etc. perhaps using JSON or YAML structures in the documentation.

Option 2 is to use either `csv reader` or `pandas` or something home-grown to read the data outside of `pyomo` and just make a ConcreteModel from the results.  This is `m2` in the example.  I think this is easiest?  Depends on the rest of your model...

#### data.csv:

```
year,zone,source,tons
2020,ca,herb,2
2020,ca,waste,3
2020,nv,waste,4
2019,az,herb,5
```

#### Script:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = AbstractModel()
# model.t = Set()  # year index
# model.a = Set()  # type of resource index
# model.q = Set()  # zone index

model.tqa = Set(dimen=3)
model.EERF = Param(model.tqa)  # feedstock production

data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename='data.csv', param=model.EERF, index=model.tqa)
instance = model.create_instance(data)
instance.pprint()

###  Option 2 ###

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv').set_index(['year', 'zone', 'source'])
model_data = df.to_dict('index')

m2 = ConcreteModel('pandas_based')

### SETS
# note:  sorted lists from sets is required to (1) avoid dupes,
#        and (2) provide lists to initializer for consistent
#        (deterministic) results.  Failure to do either will gen warnings...
m2.t = Set(initialize=sorted({t[0] for t in model_data.keys()}))
m2.q = Set(initialize=sorted({t[1] for t in model_data.keys()}))
m2.a = Set(initialize=sorted({t[2] for t in model_data.keys()}))

# a convenience for later use...
m2.tqa_idx = Set(within=m2.t*m2.q*m2.a, initialize=model_data.keys())

### PARAMS
m2.EERF = Param(m2.t, m2.q, m2.a, initialize=
    {t[0]:t[1]['tons'] for t in model_data.items()})

print(' *** Concrete Model *** ')
m2.pprint()
```

#### Output:

```
1 Set Declarations
    tqa : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     3 :    Any :    4 : {(2020, 'ca', 'herb'), (2020, 'ca', 'waste'), (2020, 'nv', 'waste'), (2019, 'az', 'herb')}

1 Param Declarations
    EERF : Size=4, Index=tqa, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key                   : Value
         (2019, 'az', 'herb') :     5
         (2020, 'ca', 'herb') :     2
        (2020, 'ca', 'waste') :     3
        (2020, 'nv', 'waste') :     4

2 Declarations: tqa EERF
 *** Concrete Model *** 
7 Set Declarations
    EERF_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     3 :  t*q*a :   12 : {(2019, 'az', 'herb'), (2019, 'az', 'waste'), (2019, 'ca', 'herb'), (2019, 'ca', 'waste'), (2019, 'nv', 'herb'), (2019, 'nv', 'waste'), (2020, 'az', 'herb'), (2020, 'az', 'waste'), (2020, 'ca', 'herb'), (2020, 'ca', 'waste'), (2020, 'nv', 'herb'), (2020, 'nv', 'waste')}
    a : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {'herb', 'waste'}
    q : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'az', 'ca', 'nv'}
    t : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {2019, 2020}
    tqa_idx : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain         : Size : Members
        None :     3 : tqa_idx_domain :    4 : {(2020, 'ca', 'herb'), (2020, 'ca', 'waste'), (2020, 'nv', 'waste'), (2019, 'az', 'herb')}
    tqa_idx_domain : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain                   : Size : Members
        None :     3 : tqa_idx_domain_index_0*a :   12 : {(2019, 'az', 'herb'), (2019, 'az', 'waste'), (2019, 'ca', 'herb'), (2019, 'ca', 'waste'), (2019, 'nv', 'herb'), (2019, 'nv', 'waste'), (2020, 'az', 'herb'), (2020, 'az', 'waste'), (2020, 'ca', 'herb'), (2020, 'ca', 'waste'), (2020, 'nv', 'herb'), (2020, 'nv', 'waste')}
    tqa_idx_domain_index_0 : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    t*q :    6 : {(2019, 'az'), (2019, 'ca'), (2019, 'nv'), (2020, 'az'), (2020, 'ca'), (2020, 'nv')}

1 Param Declarations
    EERF : Size=4, Index=EERF_index, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key                   : Value
         (2019, 'az', 'herb') :     5
         (2020, 'ca', 'herb') :     2
        (2020, 'ca', 'waste') :     3
        (2020, 'nv', 'waste') :     4
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I was able to eliminate my error by setting up each of the indices ahead of time (e.g., model.t = Set(initialize=[2020, 2030, 2040, 2050])) before loading in the spreadsheet. As long as I specify the indices ahead of time, is there still an issue with keeping the three indices separate, or do I have to create a 3-dim index each time? My full model has ~15 parameters, each with 1 to 5 indices, so I'd like to try to avoid having to make multiple new multi-dim indices if possible (which is why I wrote it indexing by three separate indices).

Comment: So you have a "blended" concrete/abstract model of some kind...  OK.  Yes, you can certainly try to keep the 1-dim indices separate.  You will have to provide a default value for parameters that are sparsely indexed.  You will probably circle back and want to capture the "valid" indices somehow when you start dealing with the variables, so punt until then!  And if the above answered your question, please hit the "check" to close the question out.